# How to add snooze/dismiss animation in android

Tags: android, android-animation, android-alarms

I tried to develop a sample Alarm Application.

I was searched Google and Stackoverflow, but no result for snooze/dismiss animation like default alarm app.

[image]

Anybody help me..

Thanks for your valuable answers..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure that you have a pic of the desired animation in your list of animation elements. (In Frame by frame or Tween ). Hope this helps.

Comment: <RelativeLayout  android = " your pic source"

Comment: And don't forget to close it with another > after including your orientation,  layout_width and  layout_height.